# Index REBUILD only works with SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to troubleshoot why my index rebuild doesn't work with `WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, ONLINE = ON)` in Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) (KB4019916) - 13.0.4435.0 (X64). I get the following error:

```
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
```

I ran `DBCC CHECKDB` which returned no errors. I have rerun with `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF` and it seems to work but takes a **very** long time. I have 86GB free disk space in TEMPDB drive, so it can't be a disk space issues.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please add the output of `select @@version` in the question

Comment: I believe this is due to low disk space on tempdb

Comment: @Shanky Added version. Is it possible it could be disk space even with 86GB free on TEMPDB drive?

Comment: I think I once read that tempdb should be sized AT LEAST as big as your largest index (cannot find reference), for maintenance purposes. That is not to say that tempdb only needs to be as big as your largest index. Is your tempdb sized accordingly and is auto-growth enabled?

Comment: @DImUser Looks like one of my indexes is 28GB, and I have 26GB free disk space on my prod server (Where the error initially happened). However, I replicated the error on my staging server which has 86GB of free tempdb disk space.. Odd..

Comment: Did someone set a max file size on tempdb files?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Maxsize is currently Unlimited